# Can I install Ubuntu without losing my files when i replace windows

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows, windows-7

Currently Im dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 an old desktop but its taken some hits over the years and now wont boot into windows anymore. And I figure maybe its time I get rid of windows completely on this computer and run Linux entirely on its own to free up more disk space. So I was was wondering if it would be possible to reinstall Ubuntu to override windows without losing my  current Ubuntu system (Ie; Pictures, files, programs. ect,)  OrIf if there was any way I could expand the Ubuntu partition of my hard drive and give myself more space.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu @Kia Yuki. If you want to access windows files, boot from ubuntu USB. There you can access windows files. Then you backup them (safer) or create a partition for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

you could format windows partition and mount it in ubuntu on startup.
or if you have time and actually want to have one partition that has all ubuntu files you could use gparted live cd and delete the windows partitin then resize ubuntu's.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using gparted to redefine the Windows partition from ntfs file system to ext4 file system for Ubuntu to use. You can use the new partition to store Movies, Music, etc. You can also use gparted to expand your existing Ubuntu storage space into the old windows space but that is a little more complicated.

Take your time and review your options by searching on `gparted` here in AskUbuntu and over the wider internet with google.